# Justify-content: space-between works incorrect

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

i have the following code

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  color: #252c3a;
}

#menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 28%;
}

#menu div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">
      <img src="img/header/logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
      <div>Home</div>
      <div>Club-Life</div>
      <div>Training</div>
      <div>Instructors</div>
      <div>Contact</div>
  </div>
```

[Chrome inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPSNO.png)

The width of the other blocks is 100%, but the header width gets bigger than the block below. I use justify-content: space-between.

Comment: How the final result should look like?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width` & `margin`

Add `flex-wrap` on the header

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    color: #252c3a;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

#menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things we need to do:

**In header:**

```
1. Remove width
```

**In #main:**

```
1. Remove width
2. Remove margin
```

**In #menu div:**

```
1. Remove everything and just add margin left
```

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/Bibeva/pen/povddJr

**Final code:**

```
header {
    height: 65px;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    color: #252c3a;
}

#menu {
    display: flex;
}

#menu div {
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
#menu {
    display: flex;
}
```

that's all , Can you try this ?